# Битрикс не грузит pdf

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на Битриксе на нем есть форма, в форме есть поле прикрепления файла

Код поля:

```
$GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->IncludeComponent(
'bitrix:main.file.input',
'drag_n_drops',
array(
'INPUT_NAME' =>$name,
'INPUT_NAME_UNSAVED' => 'FILE_NEW_TMP',
'MAX_FILE_SIZE' => '20971520', 
'MULTIPLE' => 'Y',
'MODULE_ID' => 'iblock',
'ALLOW_UPLOAD'=> 'F',
'ALLOW_UPLOAD_EXT' => 'doc,docx,xls,xlsx,txt,pdf,rar,zip,7z,jpeg,jpg',
'CUSTOM_EVENT' => $event
),null,
array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y"))
```

Загружает все файлы кроме pdf. Если изменить ALLOW_UPLOAD на "А" то pdf загружает, но мне не нужно чтобы он загружал ВСЕ файлы